# Cannot customize HERE map position listener (location) update parameters

Tags: here-api

I'm currently using HERE Map SDK on my android app but, I cannot change the position listener parameters like in native android LocationManager. The thing I want to do is to modify MIN_DISTANCE,MIN_TIME_INTERVAL,MAX_TIME_INTERVAL parameters in the position listener. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, the SDK uses the shared LocationManager in the system. So please use the regular Android APIs and it should reflect to the SDK.

Comment: Here Sdk creates its own instance, can you explain your answer with code?